# iPhone detect portrait lock setting

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to detect whether the user of my app as the portrait view lock set or not. How can I figuere this out?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: I don't think there is a way to figure that out because you don't get the orientation changed callback within the app when the portrait lock is set.

Comment: What exactly is the reason for this? Just curious - I implemented by own portrait lock for my application - just wanted to know why you needed to check this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the person that commented here: https://appcelerator.lighthouseapp.com/projects/32238/tickets/1329-able-to-programmatically-override-set-orientationlock-hardware-switch, it's impossible to detect the lock (at least, with any documented APIs).

The lock doesn't deactivate the accelerometer, though...you could detect the actual physical orientation of the device relative to what the orientation of the screen is to determine if it is locked in a particular orientation.